# Mysql update a Null column with values from another table and repeat the order

Tags: mysql

I've a table named Series

```
 ID   NAME 
 1    generic  
 2    irregular  
 3    regular
```

Another table "Sections" which contains the column "series_id" and its currently NULL (for all rows).

> ```
> id   title                  description                    series_id
> 1   Types produced        Types of data produced             NULL 
> 2   Data standard         Data and metadata standards        NULL 
> 3   Policies for access   Policies for access and sharing    NULL 
> 4   Products of Research  Products of Research               NULL
> 5   Expected info         Expected information               NULL
> 6   Period of retention   Period of data retention           NULL
> ```

I need to update the Sections table with id of Series table in a sequential order, and repeat the cycle till the end of Section rows. For example,

> ```
> id   title                  description                     series_id
> 1   Types produced        Types of data produced             1    
> 2   Data standard         Data and metadata standards        2    
> 3   Policies for access   Policies for access and sharing    3    
> 4   Products of Research  Products of Research               1
> 5   Expected info         Expected information               2
> 6   Period of retention   Period of data retention           3
> ```

I came up with an initial query, but its setting the series_id as 1 for all rows. Also, I am unsure how to repeat the series_id for the remaining rows

```
UPDATE sections t1
JOIN   series t2
ON     t1.series_id = t2.id
SET    t1.series_id = t2.id
WHERE  t1.series_id IS NULL;
```

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using the JOIN ON Series_id in Sections, where these are all NULL with the ids in t2. Perhaps youre supposed to use `UPDATE.... SET t1.series_id = t2.id`?

Comment: I tried to set the values without the join as well, but it didnt update the rows nor did it error.

Comment: Then I'd use `UPDATE Sections t1 SET t1.series_id = MOD(t1.id, x)` and figure out how `x` should look in order to achieve what you want. I don't Think you need to perform a JOIN? (I'm thinking `x` needs to be a function like `t1.id +- c` where c is a constant, and I don't know if its supposed to be an addition or subtraction as I need to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can't join both tables like that because there is no shared column.
You can use a Unique Key with an extra column that has different values for all groups of 1,2,3 (e.g. A,B,C,D,E....) which will autoincrement series_id to 1,2,3.  This might be the fastest solution. The extra column can be dropped after series_id is updated. 
Another way would be writing a procedure and using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

May be this might help:

```
SET @s =  MAX(id) From Series;
UPDATE sections t1
JOIN   series t2
ON     MOD(t1.id, @s) = MOD(t2.id, @s)
SET    t1.series_id = t2.id
WHERE  t1.series_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I suppose u mean .. ON     MOD(t1.phase_id, @s) = MOD(t2.id, @s)?? In that case its not affecting the rows.